# Two Linux Mint 16 systems Skyping--one can see both parties on webcam, the other can see neither

Tags: linux-mint, devices, camera, skype

I installed Linux Mint 16 32-bit edition on my netbook and a friend's laptop. When we Skype, I can see her live image, and I can see my own live image, so everything looks and sounds right on my end. On her end, she can see neither of our webcam images--just a static avatar for me, and a black box where her webcam image should be. Stranger still, in the Skype options under Video Devices, it says "no devices found"!  (The self-view preview there doesn't work for her, either, but does work on my system.)

That's really funny to me, because if Skype "can't find" a webcam device, how is it broadcasting from it to me over the internet? But more to the point, how can we get it so she can see me?

As a check, Skyping with her from a Windows machine also works on my end but not hers: again, I can see both her and I, and she can see neither of us.  Also, she Skyped with another person on a Windows machine, and that person had the same experience: they saw both, she saw neither.  If I Skype a Windows machine from my netbook, it works fine, both parties can see themselves and each other.  So my friend's laptop is the odd one out, but what could cause it to report 'not found' and yet actually function in sending an image out?

Comment: Rule one option out: swap laptops and both login to skype to see if it's her account or her laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even more bizarre, the situation "fixed itself" when I came to visit.  I started Skype and it just worked normally--webcam detected and could see both parties on her end.  Maybe it was a loose cable or something?  I still can't understand even that explanation, though--how it could be 'not detected' but functioning by the software that doesn't detect it.